# Too many blanks between summation symbol and its associated expression

Tags: math-mode

I am actually new to latex, so this is very basic and ridiculous question. However, I cannot eliminate the blank between f(e) and the summation symbol. Besides, the equal sign is so far from the summation symbol. How can I solve these ?

Latex Code:

```
\sum_{e \, into \, node \, v} f(e) = \sum_{e \, out \, of \, node \, v} f(e)
```

[image: Result of Latex Code]

Comment: You are welcome to TeX.SE. For my opinion it is all to remake the code. What is your complete code where the preamble is? What packages do you use, etc.

Comment: You could try something like `\sum_{\mathclap{\text{$e$ into node $v$}}} f(e) = \sum_{\mathclap{\text{$e$ into node $v$}}} f(e)` with `mathtools`. But then you might end up with the text running into the summands or the equal sign. **Edit** OK, I just checked this and it looks absolutely terrible.

Comment: never use math italic for words: `e \, into \, node \, v` the font is designed to make adjacent letters _not_ look like a word but like a product of variables.

Comment: As I write these latex codes in os-x application "pages", most of packages and math functions do not exist unfortunately.

Comment: As @moewe as already remarked, some amount of space is necessary, here, to prevent the two subscripts from clashing into each other.  I think that this is one of those cases where you need to apply (judicious) visual formatting, and insert by hand some amount of negative space.  I can’t remember off the top of my head if this can be done in Pages’ “LaTeX” too, but I think it can.

Comment: When using text I would vote for `\textnormal` rather than `\text`.

Answer (score 17):

You can use `\smashoperator` from `mathtools` (I don't recommend it) or split the subscript across two lines. Or, probably better, use suitable notation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{\text{$e$ into node $v$}}} f(e) =
\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{\text{$e$ out of node $v$}}} f(e)
\]

\[
\sum_{\substack{\text{$e$ into}\\\text{node $v$}}} f(e) =
\sum_{\substack{\text{$e$ out of}\\\text{node $v$}}} f(e)
\]

\[
\sum_{e\in v^{\leftarrow}} f(e) =
\sum_{e\in v^{\rightarrow}} f(e)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "+1" sure. :-) Best best answer.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you say `smashoperator` is not recommended?

Comment: @JAD I mean, look at the output! `;-)`

Answer (score 7):

I was elaborating over [my idea about visual formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434212/too-many-blanks-between-summation-symbol-and-its-associated-expression/434217#comment1088454_434212), when @Sebastiano’s use of `\substack` suggested a better alternative…

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}      % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{mathtools}



\begin{document}

Some text before the equation.
\begin{align}
    \sum_{\mathclap{\text{$e$ into node $v$}}} f(e)
        \mspace{9mu}&=\mspace{9mu}
        \sum_{\mathclap{\text{$e$ out of node $v$}}} f(e) 
    \\[\medskipamount]
    \sum_{\mathclap{\substack{\text{$e$ into}\\\text{node $v$}}}} f(e) &=
        \sum_{\mathclap{\substack{\text{$e$ out of}\\\text{node $v$}}}} f(e)
\end{align}
Some text after the equation.

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: Output of the code]

Comment: I want upvoted all. +1 :-)

Comment: This is what I was gonna do! +1 :)

Comment: @Au101: Yes, it's pretty obvious…  But the most comprehensive answer is—as (almost) always—egreg’s (indeed, `\smashoperator` is the way to go here!).

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution that uses the `\smashoperator` macro of the `mathtools` package. Note that there's now no gap between the summation symbols and `f(e)`. However, there's still a gap between the `=` symbol and the second summation symbol, to keep the longish material *below* the summation symbols from getting entangled.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\smashoperator' macro
\begin{document}
\[
\smashoperator{\sum_{\text{$r$ into node $v$}}}      f(e) =
\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{\text{$e$ out of node $v$}}} f(e)
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sure that is the best. +1.

Answer (score 3):

This could be one of many solutions but it is not the best.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}
\[
\sum _{e \text{ into node }v} \hspace{-.5cm}  f(e)=\sum _{e\,\, \text{out of node }v}
\hspace{-.5cm} f(e)
\]


\end{document}
```